# What is the mistake in this list iteration

Tags: java, collections

Hello i write followed code to iterate a list of nodes

```
public class RootImpl {

    private List nodes = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void processData(Object object) {

        for (String node : nodes){

        }
    }
}
```

And this code won't compile and give me errors in line:         for (String node : nodes)

java: incompatible types
  required: java.lang.String
  found:    java.lang.Object

is this code is wrong?

Comment: I think it's the type casting with the List attr. Try to use generics there: List<String> nodes = ... Sorry, long time without coding Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the variable with the appropiate types:

```
  private List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The compiler is not able to see that `nodes` has been assigned an  `ArrayList<String>`, so it interprets it as a generic `List<Object>` and issues such an error.

Answer (score 2):

The field `nodes` if of type `List`, which is why the compiler doesn't know what type its items are. You should use `List<String>`:

```
private List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
```